# How do I use fftw_plan_many_dft on a transposed array of data?

Tags: c, fftw

I have a 2D array of data stored in column-major (Fortran-style) format, and I'd like to take the FFT of each *row*. I would like to avoid transposing the array (it is not square). For example, my array

```
fftw_complex* data = new fftw_complex[21*256];
```

contains entries `[r0_val0, r1_val0,..., r20_val0, r0_val1,...,r20_val255]`.

I can use `fftw_plan_many_dft` to make a plan to solve each of the 21 FFTs in-place in the `data` array if it is *row*-major, e.g. `[r0_val0, r0_val1,..., r0_val255, r1_val0,...,r20_val255]`:

```
int main() {
  int N = 256;
  int howmany = 21;
  fftw_complex* data = new fftw_complex[N*howmany];
  fftw_plan p;

  // this plan is OK
  p = fftw_plan_many_dft(1,&N,howmany,data,NULL,1,N,data,NULL,1,N,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
  // do stuff...

  return 0;
}
```

According to the documentation ([section 4.4.1 of the FFTW manual](http://fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html)), the signature for the function is

```
fftw_plan fftw_plan_many_dft(int rank, const int *n, int howmany,
                              fftw_complex *in, const int *inembed,
                              int istride, int idist,
                              fftw_complex *out, const int *onembed,
                              int ostride, int odist,
                              int sign, unsigned flags);
```

and I should be able to use the `stride` and `dist` parameters to set the indexing. From what I can understand from the documentation, the entries in the array to be transformed are indexed as `in + j*istride + k*idist` where `j=0..n-1` and `k=0..howmany-1`. (My arrays are 1D and there are `howmany` of them). However, the following code results in a seg. fault (**edit:** the stride length is **wrong**, see update below):

```
int main() {
  int N = 256;
  int howmany = 21;
  fftw_complex* data = new fftw_complex[N*howmany];
  fftw_plan p;

  // this call results in a seg. fault.
  p = fftw_plan_many_dft(1,&N,howmany,data,NULL,N,1,data,NULL,N,1,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);

  return 0;
}
```

### Update:

I made an error choosing the stride length. The correct call is (the correct stride length is `howmany`, not `N`):

```
int main() {
  int N = 256;
  int howmany = 21;
  fftw_complex* data = new fftw_complex[N*howmany];
  fftw_plan p;

  // OK
  p = fftw_plan_many_dft(1,&N,howmany,data,NULL,howmany,1,data,NULL,howmany,1,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
  // do stuff  

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function works as documented. I made an error with the stride length, which should actually be `howmany` in this case. I have updated the question to reflect this.

I find the documentation for FFTW is somewhat difficult to comprehend without examples (I could just be illiterate...), so I'm posting a more detailed example below, comparing the usual use of `fftw_plan_dft_1d` with `fftw_plan_many_dft`. To recap, in the case of `howmany` arrays with length `N` that are stored in a contiguous block of memory referenced as `in`, the array elements `j` for each transform `k` are

```
*(in + j*istride + k*idist)
```

The following two pieces of code are equivalent. In the first, the conversion from some 2D array is done explicitly, and in the second the `fftw_plan_many_dft` call is used to do everything in-place.

**Explicit Copy**

```cpp
int N, howmany;
// ...
fftw_complex* data = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(N*howmany*sizeof(fftw_complex));
// ... load data with howmany arrays of length N 
int istride, idist;
// ... if data is column-major, set istride=howmany, idist=1
//    if data is row-major, set istride=1, idist=N

fftw_complex* in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(N*sizeof(fftw_complex));
fftw_complex* out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(N*sizeof(fftw_complex));
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N,in,out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
for (int k = 0; k < howmany; ++k) {
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    in[j] = data[j*istride + k*idist];
  }
  fftw_execute(p);
  // do something with out
}
```

**Plan Many**

```cpp
int N, howmany;
// ...
fftw_complex* data = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(N*howmany*sizeof(fftw_complex));
// ... load data with howmany arrays of length N 
int istride, idist;
// ... if data is column-major, set istride=howmany, idist=1
//    if data is row-major, set istride=1, idist=N

fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_many_dft(1,&N,howmany,data,NULL,howmany,1,data,NULL,howmany,1,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
fftw_execute(p);
```

Comment: I am not sure this is correct @Dylan.  If you change your data array `in` then you have to run `fftw_plan_dft_1d` a second time using your new input array.  Although I can't be sure it will give you an error as written, I can tell you the documentation explicitly warns against it (page 4 of the pdf manual to version 3.2.2).

Comment: @kalu I think you may have misunderstood the manual. Are you referring to the sentence that begins “If you want to transform a different array of the same size”? That is in reference to using a different array, rather than to changing the contents of the existing one.